# Moving list view elements to another list view in a separate activity

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-intent

I'm having trouble understanding how to use Intent to move list view elements. So I've made a separate project to practice this before actually figuring it out in my app. Basically, I want to have a "Favorites" activity that can be populated from something like a search results page. Instead of a search results page, I've just created a list view with some sample elements in them with a favorites button in each. I just need some guidance on how to go from there. Here is my code so far

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    generateList();
    listView.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.item_view, data));
}


private void generateList() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        data.add("row/item " + i);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private int layout;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> 
    objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        layout = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup 
    parent) {
        ViewHolder minViewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.title = (TextView)  
            convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text);
            viewHolder.button = (Button)  
            convertView.findViewById(R.id.favorites_button);
            viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
               {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "sent item " + position + "  
                    to favorites tab", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   // data.remove(position);
                    MyListAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            minViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            minViewHolder.title.setText(getItem(position));
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
public class ViewHolder{
    TextView title;
    Button button;
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" /> </RelativeLayout>
```

item_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_text"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="fav"
    android:id="@+id/favorites_button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I haven't set up a second activity because I wanted ideas on how to create a list that is empty but can be populated by that favorites button press. Any help at all is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Update arraylist according to favourite and call

```
adapter.notifyDataChanged();
```

if listview is same,

otherwise for different listview call another listview with adapter and new filtered arraylist

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following what you're saying. Can you explain a little more?